# Compiling multiple java files within a single file?

Tags: java, compilation, program-entry-point, helper

Trying to compile a multi file package. Needing to compile via: `javac mainfile.java` while also compiling all the other (about 4 other .java files) at the same time through the one file? I have tried using statements like extend and `import package.*` Any help would be appreciated.

I have used different compiling methods and arguments but trying to do it just by only inserting `javac mainfile.java` and `java mainfile`

Summary: Trying to compile multiple java files at once, through java compiling a single file.

My current code for the main file:

```
package mypackage;
import mypackage.*;

public class mainfile{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Myfile.main(args) //run main from other file
}
}
```

Edit: Sorry for the lack of information, when compiling, the compiler returns:

```
MainFile.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
         Myfile.main(args);
         ^
symbol: variable Myfile
location: class mainfile
1 error
```

Comment: You describe your goal and your attempt, but not what goes wrong (any error messages). Please add that. Also: you don't need `import mypackage.*` when the file is in the `package mypackage` itself. Lastly: your class is named `mypackage.mainfail`. You'll need to use that as the argument to `java`: it always requires the full class name.

Comment: Your file MainFile.java should contain a class ``public class MainFile``

Comment: @tobias Could you please explain your answer? Why compiling several files at once works and why doesn't what the OP is trying to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`javac` as a tool does not do what you want. But, that's why other tools exist.

What you're asking for boils down to 'I want a build system'. The vast majority of java projects use [maven](https://maven.apache.org) or [gradle](https://gradle.org).

It would seem like this works fine:

```
javac -sourcepath src src/mainfile.java
```

but you'd be deceived. That will merely compile all source files that are directly referenced by the code in `mainfile.java`, but there are many other ways to refer to code, such as SPI, reflection, XML config files. The vast majority of java projects will end up using some construct that ends up 'breaking' the `-sourcepath` "trick" sooner rather than later, which is presumably why all java projects use a build system instead of relying on `-sourcepath`.

Note that all source files act as if they have:

```
import java.lang.*;
import yourownpackage.*;
```

at the top, whether you write this out or not. And, `import` is java-ese for 'alias'. `import foo.bar.Baz;` means: Whenever 'Baz' appears in this file as a type, assume I meant to write 'foo.bar.Baz', and **that is all**: `import foo.bar.Baz` does not run any code that is in the Baz class whatsoever. If you don't use Baz, then the class file produced doesn't mention Baz at all. This will also not cause javac to then compile your entire directory.